# Javascript - Chain multiple Fetch promises

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

I have this method who performs 3 window.fetch

```
   const API_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/'
  , API = {
    'getArtistLyric': artist => {
      return fetch(`${API_URL}artist?name=${artist}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        const artistID = JSON.parse(res).message.body.artist_list[0].artist.artist_id;

        console.log('Artist ID is:', artistID);

        fetch(`${API_URL}artist/albums/?artist_id=${artistID}`)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(resp => {
          const trackID = JSON.parse(resp).message.body.album_list[0].album.album_id;

          console.log('Random Track ID is:', trackID);

          fetch(`${API_URL}artist/album/songsnippet?track_id=${trackID}`)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(response => {
            const lyricSnippet = JSON.parse(response).message;

            console.log('Track Id lyric snippet is:', lyricSnippet);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.error(err);
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      });
    }
  }
```

Now i want to call it like this

```
API.getArtistLyric('Prodigy').then(res).catch(err);
```

What's the best practice here?

Comment: There are some `return`s missing

Comment: @Andreas looks like but i tried many times, can't get it to work correctly

Comment: Calling `JSON.parse` on the result of a `response.json()` is either a mistake or indicates a weird server response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a chain requests it's better to use async/await :

```
async func(){
    let response = await /* some request */
    let res = await /* another request */ 
    ...
    return results;
}
```

Here you can use try/catch syntax and wrap specific request :

```
try {
    let response = await... 
} catch ( exception)  {
   ...
}
```

Also you can wrap a couple of requests.

Answer (score 1):

```js
(async() => {
     const API_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/';
     const API = {
        getArtistLyric: async(artist) => {
        try {
              const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}artist?name=${artist}`);
              const artistID = JSON.parse(res.json()).message.body.artist_list[0].artist.artist_id;

              console.log('Artist ID is:', artistID);

              const resp = await fetch(`${API_URL}artist/albums/?artist_id=${artistID}`);
              const trackID = JSON.parse(resp.json()).message.body.album_list[0].album.album_id;

              console.log('Random Track ID is:', trackID);

              const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}artist/album/songsnippet?track_id=${trackID}`);
            
              const lyricSnippet = JSON.parse(response.json()).message;
              console.log('Track Id lyric snippet is:', lyricSnippet);
              return lyricSnippet;
          } catch (e) {

            console.error(e);
         }
           
        }
      }



    try {
        const art = await API.getArtistLyric('Prodigy');
        console.log(art);
    } catch (e ){
       console.error(e);
    }

})()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link regarding chaining promises: https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

Here's the core idea:

> It looks like this:
>
> ```
>  new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
>
>   setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 1000); // (*)
>
> }).then(function(result) { // (**)
>
>   alert(result); // 1   return result * 2;
>
> }).then(function(result) { // (***)
>
>   alert(result); // 2   return result * 2;
>
> }).then(function(result) {
>
>   alert(result); // 4   return result * 2;
>
> });
> ```
>
> The idea is that the result is passed through the chain of .then
>   handlers.
>
> Here the flow is:
>
> The initial promise resolves in 1 second (*), Then the .then handler
>   is called (**). The value that
>
> it returns is passed to the next .then handler (***) …and so on.