# How to chain multiple fetch() promises?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

The following code fetches a json list and then does another fetch call for each list item to change their values. The problem is that it’s not done synchronously. “new” is printed to the console before “update”.

```
fetch(API_URL_DIARY)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log("old", data);
  return data;
})
.then(data => {
  data.forEach(function(e, index,array) {
    fetch(API_URL_FOOD_DETAILS + e.foodid)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      array[index] = {...e, ...data};
      console.log("update");
    })
  });

  console.log("new", data)
});
```

**Update**

Here's how I incorporated @Andy's solution:

```
function fetchFoodDetails(id, index) {
  return fetch(API_URL_FOOD_DETAILS + id)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
      return [index, data];
  });
}

function fetchDiary() {
  return fetch(API_URL_DIARY)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    return data;
  })
}

(async () => {
  const data = await fetchDiary();
  console.log("old", JSON.stringify(data));

  const promises = data.map((food, index) => fetchFoodDetails(food.id, index));
  await Promise.all(promises).then(responses => {
    responses.map(response => {
      data[response[0]] = {...data[response[0]], ...response[1]};
      console.log("update");
    })
  });
  console.log('new', JSON.stringify(data));
})();
```

It was more difficult so I went with @connoraworden's solution. But I think it can be simplified.

Thanks for all your answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - Chain multiple Fetch promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48807469/javascript-chain-multiple-fetch-promises)

Comment: Are you wanting to log "new" after the `foreach` or after each of the fetch request inside of the `foreach`?

Comment: @connoraworden after the forEach. It's because I need to render the list with React

Comment: Cool, I've added an answer that should be what you're looking for

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best way to go about this is to use `Promise.all()` and `map()`.

What map will do in this context return all the promises from `fetch`.

Then what will happen is `await` will make your code execution synchronous as it'll wait for all of the promise to be resolved before continuing to execute.

The problem with using `forEach` here is that it doesn't wait for asynchronous request to be completed before it moves onto the next item.

The code that you should be using here is:

```
fetch(API_URL_DIARY)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log("old", data);
        return data;
    })
    .then(async data => {
        await Promise.all(data.map((e, index, array) => {
            return fetch(API_URL_FOOD_DETAILS + e.foodid)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    array[index] = {...e, ...data};
                    console.log("update");
                })
        }));

        console.log("new", data)
    });
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution. I learned a lot. Many thanks @connoraworden

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` is a Promise. This is asyncronous call, so the "new" console.log runs before finished all the promises. Use `Promise.all()` for that.

You can do this so:

```
fetch(API_URL_DIARY)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log("old", data);
    return data;
  })
  .then(data => {
    return Promise.all(data.map(food =>
      fetch(API_URL_FOOD_DETAILS + food.foodid)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(json => {
          // do some work with json
          return json
        })
    ))
  })
  .then(data => console.log('new', data))
```

Comment: The code looks right but ```data``` is undefined at the end, and "update" is printed after "new". I'm not sure that returning ```.forEach()``` promise works

Comment: You are right, you must wait for all the promise resolved. I edited the answer code

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `forEach` here. The best solution is to use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) which waits for an array of promises (`fetch` is a promise) to all resolve, after which you can process the data.

Here I've created a dummy fetch function with some sample data to quickly show you how that works.

```js
const dummyObj = {
  main: [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 5 } ],
 other: {
    1: 'data1',
    2: 'data2',
    3: 'data3',
    4: 'data4',
    5: 'data5',
    6: 'data6',
    7: 'data7',
  }  
}

// The summy function simply returns a subset of the sample
// data depending on the type and id params after 2 seconds
// to mimic an API call
function dummyFetch(type, id) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(id ? dummyObj[type][id] : dummyObj[type]);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

// In the first fetch we display the data, just
// like you did in your example
dummyFetch('main')
.then(data => {
  console.log("old", data);
  return data;
})
.then(data => {

  // Instead of a forEach use Array.map to iterate over the
  // data and create a new fetch for each
  const promises = data.map(o => dummyFetch('other', o.id));

  // You can then wait for all promises to be resolved
  Promise.all(promises).then((data) => {

    // Here you would iterate over the returned group data
    // (as in your example)
    // I'm just logging the new data as a string
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

    // And, finally, there's the new log at the end
    console.log("new", data)
  });
});
```

Here's the `async/await` version:

```js
const dummyObj = {
  main: [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 5 } ],
 other: {
    1: 'data1',
    2: 'data2',
    3: 'data3',
    4: 'data4',
    5: 'data5',
    6: 'data6',
    7: 'data7',
  }  
}

function dummyFetch(type, id) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(id ? dummyObj[type][id] : dummyObj[type]);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

(async () => {
  const oldData = await dummyFetch('main');
  console.log("old", oldData);
  const promises = oldData.map(o => dummyFetch('other', o.id));
  const newData = await Promise.all(promises);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(newData));
  console.log('new', newData);
})();
```

Comment: I appreciate the detailed answer, which I upvoted. Though it was more difficult to incorporate with my code. I've added it to my original post so you can see it.

Answer (score 1):

**Storing multiple responses in a single array**

The following code fetches multiple keywords in queries and stores all the response of all three responses to the **all** array

```
let queries = ["food", "movies", "news"]
let all = []

queries.forEach((keyword)=>{
  let [subres] = await Promise.all([fetch(`https://reddit.com/r/${keyword}/hot.json?limit=100`).then((response) => response.json())]);
  all.push(subres)
})

//now you can use the data globally or use the data to fetch more data
console.log(all)
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to chain multiple fetch() promises?

You do it like how you have been doing it, just append another `.then()`

```
fetch(API_URL_DIARY)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log("old", data);
  return data;
})
.then(data => {
  data.forEach(function(e, index,array) {
    fetch(API_URL_FOOD_DETAILS + e.foodid)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      array[index] = {...e, ...data};
      console.log("update");
    })
    .then(()=>{
      console.log("new", data)  
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: I think the OP means to have "new" printed after _all_ the update fetches in the `forEach` are completed, so this won't work.

Comment: If OP can confirm your suspicion, I'll gladly update my answer @Andy

Answer (score 0):

If you want show only once "console.log("new", data)", you can check it with the index, like this:

```
fetch(API_URL_DIARY)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log("old", data);
      return data;
    })
    .then(data => {
      data.forEach(function(e, index,array) {
        fetch(API_URL_FOOD_DETAILS + e.foodid)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          array[index] = {...e, ...data};
          console.log("update");
           if ((data.length - 1) === index) { // CHECK INDEX HERE IF IS THE LAST
             console.log("new", data)
           }
        })
      });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need a recursive function to do this.

```
    fetch(API_URL_DIARY)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log("old", data);
      return data;
    })
    .then(data => {

    recursiveFetch(data)

    });

function recursiveFetch(initialData){
        e = initialData[initialData.length-1]; //taking the last item in array
        fetch(API_URL_FOOD_DETAILS + e.foodid)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          array[index] = {...e, ...data};
          console.log("update");
          initialData.pop() // removing last item from array, which is already processed
          if(initialData.length > 0)
             recursiveFetch(initialData)
        })
}
```

Note: This is an untested code.