# Broken promise chain "then"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

Here I am again, with another question. My promise chain is broken somewhere, but I can't figure out why.
My task is to fetch first API (success), second API (success) and then third API with the use of the information from the second one. And here where my codes fails. Console is showing me that `resultTwo` is void.

Why if I used the same logic?
How can I repeat in a "clean way" the third call (I need to call the third API for 5 different days)?

```
const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});
  const [details, setDetails] = useState({})

 const search = evt => {
    if (evt.key === "Enter") {
      fetch(`${api.base}forecast?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
          setWeather(result);
          setQuery('');
          console.log(result);
          return result;
        })
        .then((result) => {
           fetch(`${api.base}onecall?lat=${result.city.coord.lat}&lon=${result.city.coord.lon}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
            .then((res)=>res.json())
            .then(resultTwo =>{
                setDetails(resultTwo)
                console.log(resultTwo)
                return resultTwo
              })
          })
            .then((resultTwo) => {
              const data1 = fetch(`${api.base}aggregated/day?lat=${resultTwo.lat}&lon=${resultTwo.lon}month=${moment().format("M")}&day=${moment().format("D")}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
              data1.then((res)=>res.json())
                  .then(resultThree=>{
                      console.log(resultThree)
                  })
              })

    }
  }
```

Comment: You should probably make the functions `async` and wrap them in `Promise.all()` to aggregate their results.

Comment: Yeah, I know that async/await could be easier, but do you have any example maybe? I'm lost with this async code when I need to take care at the same time of  passing the data from one api to another, it got a little bit messy ;d

Comment: Try here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075049/how-to-chain-multiple-fetch-promises

Comment: @k-wasilewski That's not possible because the three requests depend on each other so they have to be done sequentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is broken in two places:

```js
const [query, setQuery] = useState('')
const [weather, setWeather] = useState({})
const [details, setDetails] = useState({})



const search = evt => {
  if (evt.key === "Enter") {
    fetch(`${api.base}forecast?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
        setWeather(result);
        setQuery('');
        console.log(result);
        return result;
      })
      .then((result) => {
          // *** RETURN WAS MISSING HERE! ***
          return fetch(`${api.base}onecall?lat=${result.city.coord.lat}&lon=${result.city.coord.lon}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
          .then((res)=>res.json())
          .then(resultTwo =>{
              setDetails(resultTwo)
              console.log(resultTwo)
              return resultTwo
            })
        })
          .then((resultTwo) => {
            const data1 = fetch(`${api.base}aggregated/day?lat=${resultTwo.lat}&lon=${resultTwo.lon}month=${moment().format("M")}&day=${moment().format("D")}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
            // *** RETURN WAS MISSING HERE AS WELL! ***
            return data1.then((res)=>res.json())
                .then(resultThree=>{
                    console.log(resultThree)
                })
            })

  }
}
```

Also, the code's readability could be greatly improved using `async`/`await`:

```js
const [query, setQuery] = useState('')
const [weather, setWeather] = useState({})
const [details, setDetails] = useState({})

const search = async evt => {
  if (evt.key === 'Enter') {
    try {
      const forecastResponse = await fetch(`${api.base}forecast?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
      const forecastResult = await forecastResponse.json()
      setWeather(forecastResult)
      setQuery('')
      console.log(forecastResult)

      const onecallResponse = await fetch(`${api.base}onecall?lat=${forecastResult.city.coord.lat}&lon=${forecastResult.city.coord.lon}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
      const onecallResult = await onecallResponse.json()
      setDetails(onecallResult)
      console.log(onecallResult)

      const aggregatedResponse = await fetch(`${api.base}aggregated/day?lat=${onecallResult.lat}&lon=${onecallResult.lon}month=${moment().format('M')}&day=${moment().format('D')}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
      const aggregatedResult = await aggregatedResponse.json()
      console.log(aggregatedResult)
    } catch (e) { // Catch error to avoid unhandled promise rejection
      console.error(e)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Woah, amazing man. Thank you so much! Awesome annswer, exactly what I needed!

Comment: @CherryDT its a dumb question but why we need 'return' at these places ?

Comment: Because in the callback that you pass into `then` you can return a value or a promise that later resolves to a value, and that will be what is passed into the next `then` callback. In case you returned a promise, it is awaited before the next handler gets called with its resolved value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Async, Await to avoid the chain. You can create generic method for getdata from api. It will help to resolve your issue.